# Android, launch a video from another device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, google-cardboard

I'm working in a project were from a device i need a start and stop a video (with cardbox) on another device connected by bluetooth.
Is there any easy why to do this?

Sorry for the question but i'm not native android developer, i'm using cordova to create the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, as long as you transfer some control data via Bluetooth. e.g. via SPP or other profile.